# JupyterLab crashes when printing df.head()

Tags: python, pandas, crash, jupyter-lab

I am using `JupyterLab` version 0.32.1, `pandas` version 0.22.0, `scipy` version 0.19.1, `numpy` version 1.14.2. My `python` version is:
`3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]`.

I have realised that `JupyterLab` crashes when I attempt to do the following:

```
import scipy
import numpy
import pandas as pd

filename ='pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(filename)
data.head()
```

The webpage with my notebook restarts automatically every time I run the cell with `data.head()`. The same happens if you try to read (with `pandas`) a csv from a `url`.

Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround available?

NB: please find the `csv` file here: https://github.com/cxd/au.id.cxd.Math/blob/master/data/test-pima-diabetes/raw-pima-indians-diabetes.csv

Comment: It isn't crashing for me. I tried that same with same dataset

Comment: `Pandas version '0.20.3' ` , `scipy version 0.19.1` , `numpy version 1.13.3`.

Comment: For me it gives the following error: r_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 31, saw 3